# get color with Raycaster

Tags: aframe

how can one get the color of the intersection of a Raycaster and an object?

for example, if the Raycaster is pointed at a box with a material with a Hexcode color, it would be nice to return the color code of the object.

And if object has an image for a texture, Id like to get the color of the specific pixel the Raycast line is intersecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**0) Intersection information**

Let's go with the `raycaster-intersection` event. If you add an event listener to the raycasting entity

```
rayEl.addEventListener("raycaster-intersection", (e)=> {
// e contains useful information
```

the event detail contains two arrays:
a) `els` contain intersected elements (entities)
b) `intersections` contain intersection details (exact points etc.)

You can check them in this fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d3kg82rh/2/)

**1) Grabbing the color**

If your entity has a hexcode color defined in either way:

```
<a-sphere color="#af0faf"></a-sphere>
<a-box material="color: #af0faf"></a-box>
```

you can access it from the `material` component:

```
let el = e.detail.els[0]
el.getAttribute("material").color
el.components.material.color
```

**2) Grabbing the texture color**

This is quite difficult, and i'm not sure how can be done otherwise.

The mentioned `e.detail.intersections` contains the intersected point on the UV map. It has the (x, y) point where x,y are ranging from <-0.5, 0.5>. 
To translate it to the pixel color, you can create a temporary `<canvas>`, fill it with the texture, grab the context, and get the pixel color.

```
var c // the canvas element with the texture
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var pixel = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data 
// a) x, y are -0.5 - 0.5 so it needs rescaling to the canvas 
// (simply multiply by the canvas size)
// b) pixel contains RGBA values
```